# Writing a thread safe modular counter in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

*Full disclaimer:* this is not really a homework, but I tagged it as such because it is mostly a self-learning exercise rather than actually "for work".

Let's say I want to write a simple thread safe modular counter in Java. That is, if the modulo `M` is 3, then the counter should cycle through `0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, …`  ad infinitum.

Here's one attempt:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class AtomicModularCounter {
    private final AtomicInteger tick = new AtomicInteger();
    private final int M;

    public AtomicModularCounter(int M) {
        this.M = M;
    }
    public int next() {
        return modulo(tick.getAndIncrement(), M);
    }
    private final static int modulo(int v, int M) {
        return ((v % M) + M) % M;
    }
}
```

My analysis (which may be faulty) of this code is that since it uses [`AtomicInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), it's quite thread safe even without any explicit `synchronized` method/block.

Unfortunately the "algorithm" itself doesn't quite "work", because when `tick` wraps around `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, `next()` may return the wrong value depending on the modulo `M`. That is:

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE); // true
System.out.println(modulo(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 3)); // 1
System.out.println(modulo(Integer.MIN_VALUE, 3)); // 1
```

That is, two calls to `next()` will return `1, 1` when the modulo is 3 and `tick` wraps around.

There may also be an issue with `next()` getting out-of-order values, e.g.:

1. *Thread1* calls `next()`
2. *Thread2* calls `next()`
3. *Thread2* completes `tick.getAndIncrement()`, returns *x*
4. *Thread1* completes `tick.getAndIncrement()`, returns *y = x+1 (mod M)*

Here, barring the forementioned wrapping problem, *x* and *y* are indeed the two correct values to return for these two `next()` calls, but depending on how the counter behavior is specified, it can be argued that they're out of order. That is, we now have *(Thread1, y)* and *(Thread2, x)*, but maybe it should really be specified that *(Thread1, x)* and *(Thread2, y)* is the "proper" behavior.

So by some definition of the words, `AtomicModularCounter` is *thread-safe*, but not actually *atomic*.

So the questions are:

- Is my analysis correct? If not, then please point out any errors.
- Is my last statement above using the correct terminology? If not, what is the correct statement?
- If the problems mentioned above are real, then how would you fix it?
- Can you fix it without using `synchronized`, by harnessing the atomicity of `AtomicInteger`?
- How would you write it such that `tick` itself is range-controlled by the modulo and never even gets a chance to wraps over `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

  - We can assume `M` is at least an order smaller than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` if necessary

---

#### Appendix

Here's a `List` analogy of the out-of-order "problem".

- *Thread1* calls `add(first)`
- *Thread2* calls `add(second)`

Now, if we have the list updated succesfully with two elements added, but `second` comes before `first`, which is at the end, is that "thread safe"?

If that is "thread safe", then what is it not? That is, if we specify that in the above scenario, `first` should always come before `second`, what is that concurrency property called? (I called it "atomicity" but I'm not sure if this is the correct terminology).

For what it's worth, what is the `Collections.synchronizedList` behavior with regards to this out-of-order aspect?

Comment: Interesting question. This gives me a [deja vu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399191/write-a-java-class-to-have-only-five-instance-of-it-created#comments-3399237) ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can see you just need a variation of the getAndIncrement()  method

```
public final int getAndIncrement(int modulo) {
    for (;;) {
        int current = atomicInteger.get();
        int next = (current + 1) % modulo;
        if (atomicInteger.compareAndSet(current, next))
            return current;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this looks like it will work. Wow, can other people comment? Wow.

Comment: As for a comment, you need to stop wow'ing, and yes, this is almost as good as it gets, if you want to avoid locking. For a non-blocking implementation, CAS (or equivalent) is the cornerstone operation to make it happen.

(If it is really costly to create a whole object just to be able to perform CAS'es, AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater and friends is the way to go, but only if memory overhead is really important, as it does wonders to clutter the code :) ).

Comment: By the way, it should be noted that this will perform horribly if there are many frequent writers. I know this wasn't in the aims of your question, just sayin', for our readers at home.

Comment: @Dimtris, good contribution, however, if you have many frequent writers you have a serious problem because it means you have many threads calling this rather than doing anything useful with the number generated.

Comment: @Peter, generally I agree, but it still may be a useful comment to make. For example, it's not unimaginable that someone might think useful to wrap a CHM and do, for each update (which are fast), a custom counting of some sort in some other variable(s) (say, count the gets and the puts).

Comment: @Dimtris. true, but the get and put would take some time (about 2x longer) and you would need to do something useful with the data (or get the data from somewhere to put it) and if that took 10x longer you can keep (1+2) * 10 = 30 cores busy and get little contension.  In any case a performance counter doesn't need to be 100% accurate. If its 98% accurate that is fine IMHO so I would just use a non-volatile field (to minimise the cost of the counter) and take into account that a few percent of increments might be lost.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that aside from the wrapping, it's fine. When two method calls are effectively simultaneous, you can't guarantee which will happen first.

The code is still atomic, because whichever actually happens first, they can't interfere with each other at all.

Basically if you have code which tries to rely on the order of simultaneous calls, you already have a race condition. Even if in the calling code one thread gets to the start of the `next()` call before the other, you can imagine it coming to the end of its time-slice before it gets *into* the `next()` call - allowing the second thread to get in there.

If the `next()` call had any other side effect - e.g. it printed out "Starting with thread (thread id)" and *then* returned the next value, then it wouldn't be atomic; you'd have an observable difference in behaviour. As it is, I think you're fine.

One thing to think about regarding wrapping: you can make the counter last an awful lot longer before wrapping if you use an `AtomicLong` :)

EDIT: I've just thought of a neat way of avoiding the wrapping problem in all realistic scenarios:

- Define some large number M * 100000 (or whatever). This should be chosen to be large enough to not be hit too often (as it will reduce performance) but small enough that you can expect the "fixing" loop below to be effective before too many threads have added to the tick to cause it to wrap.
- When you fetch the value with `getAndIncrement()`, check whether it's greater than this number. If it is, go into a "reduction loop" which would look something like this:

  ```
  long tmp;
  while ((tmp = tick.get()) > SAFETY_VALUE))
  {
      long newValue = tmp - SAFETY_VALUE;
      tick.compareAndSet(tmp, newValue);
  }
  ```

Basically this says, "We need to get the value back into a safe range, by decrementing some multiple of the modulus" (so that it doesn't change the value mod M). It does this in a tight loop, basically working out what the new value should be, but only making a change if nothing else has changed the value in between.

It could cause a problem in *pathological* conditions where you had an infinite number of threads trying to increment the value, but I think it would realistically be okay.

Comment: Yes, obviously `AtomicLong` was considered, but since this is a "homework", I'd like to learn from this exercise as much as I can rather than coming up with a practical but non-educational "solution" like that =)

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Edited with a slightly crazy scheme.

Comment: @Jon: oh believe me, I mentally experimented with various crazy schemes like that (what you aptly called "reduction loop"). That's the origin of the assumption about the modulo being at least an order of magnitude smaller than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. In the end I could never convince myself that they're air-tightly correct. At that point it may be better to just use explicitly `synchronized` code and work with a `volatile int` instead.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: I think in this case (particularly using `AtomicLong`) it would be absolutely fine in any case that's even *slightly* sane. Even with many threads, as you hit the safety limit you'd have to have *new* threads still trying to just get the next value sufficiently quickly to block all those trying to reduce it. Basically I'd be happy enough that this was safe. If you've got *that* many threads, your computer will blow up anyway :)

Comment: There was a recent SO question on how long it would take for an incremented `long` to overflow.  The answer was about more than a lifetime, assuming today's hardware.

Comment: It's me - I find Peter Lawrey's answer better, and I'd prefer to see that on top.

Comment: @Dimitris: So you don't *actually* find the answer "not useful" (unhelpful, inaccurate etc)?

Comment: Your answer *is* useful and helpful, but less so than Peter's answer, so I would prefer the viewer to see his answer first. Did I break some rule?

Comment: @Dimitris: Not a rule as such - but *I* certainly reserve downvoting for genuinely "not useful" answers, as per the tooltip. To me, a downvote is an indication that an answer is seriously flawed - not just "not as good as another one". You can choose to vote however you wish though, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the atomicity problem: I don't believe that it's possible for the Counter itself to provide behaviour to guarantee the semantics you're implying.

I think we have a thread doing some work

```
  A - get some stuff (for example receive a message)
  B - prepare to call Counter
  C - Enter Counter <=== counter code is now in control
  D - Increment
  E - return from Counter <==== just about to leave counter's control
  F - application continues
```

The mediation you're looking for concerns the "payload" identity ordering established at A.

For example two threads each read a message - one reads X, one reads Y. You want to ensure that X gets the first counter increment, Y gets the second, even though the two threads are running simultaneously, and may be scheduled arbitarily across 1 or more CPUs.

Hence any ordering must be imposed across all the steps A-F, and enforced by some concurrency countrol outside of the Counter. For example:

```
pre-A - Get a lock on Counter (or other lock)
  A - get some stuff (for example receive a message)
  B - prepare to call Counter
  C - Enter Counter <=== counter code is now in control
  D - Increment
  E - return from Counter <==== just about to leave counter's control
  F - application continues
post- F - release lock
```

Now we have a guarantee at the expense of some parallelism; the threads are waiting for each other. When strict ordering is a requirement this does tend to limit concurrency; it's a common problem in messaging systems.

Concerning the List question. Thread-safety should be seen in terms of interface guarantees. There is absolute minimum requriement: the List must be resilient in the face of simultaneous access from several threads. For example, we could imagine an unsafe list that could deadlock or leave the list mis-linked so that any iteration would loop for ever. The next requirement is that we should specify behaviour when two threads access at the same time. There's lots of cases, here's a few

```
a). Two threads attempt to add
b). One thread adds item with key "X", another attempts to delete the item with key "X"
C). One thread is iterating while a second thread is adding
```

Providing that the implementation has clearly defined behaviour in each case it's thread-safe. The interesting question is what behaviours are convenient.

We can simply synchronise on the list, and hence easily give well-understood behaviour for a and b. However that comes at a cost in terms of parallelism. And I'm arguing that it had no value to do this, as you still need to synchronise at some higher level to get useful semantics. So I would have an interface spec saying "Adds happen in any order".

As for iteration - that's a hard problem, have a look at what the Java collections promise: not a lot!

[This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07233.html) , which discusses Java collections may be interesting.

Comment: Could you address the `List` analogy? I'll repeat here more explicitly: if _Thread1_ calls `add(first)`, and before it's able to complete, _Thread2_ calls `add(second)`, is it thread safe if `second` comes before `first` as long as both are guaranteed to be successfully added?

Comment: Edited to address that question.

Answer (score 1):

*Atomic* (as I understand) refers to the fact that an intermediate state is not observable from outside. `atomicInteger.incrementAndGet()` is atomic, while `return this.intField++;` is not, in the sense that in the former, you can not observe a state in which the integer has been incremented, but has not yet being returned.

As for *thread-safety*, authors of Java Concurrency in Practice provide one definition in their book:

> A class is thread-safe if it behaves
>   correctly when accessed from multiple
>   threads, regardless of the scheduling
>   or interleaving of the execution of
>   those threads by the runtime
>   environment, and with no additional
>   synchronization or other coordination
>   on the part of the calling code.

(My personal opinion follows)

---

> Now, if we have the list
>   updated succesfully with two elements
>   added, but second comes before first,
>   which is at the end, is that "thread
>   safe"?

If thread1 entered the entry set of the mutex object (In case of Collections.synchronizedList() the list itself) before thread2, it is guaranteed that `first` is positioned ahead than `second` in the list after the update. This is because the `synchronized` keyword uses fair lock. Whoever sits ahead of the queue gets to do stuff first. Fair locks can be quite expensive and you can also have unfair locks in java (through the use of java.util.concurrent utilities). If you'd do that, then there is no such guarantee.

However, the java platform is not a real time computing platform, so you can't predict how long a piece of code requires to run. Which means, if you want `first` ahead of `second`, you need to ensure this explicitly in java. It is impossible to ensure this through "controlling the timing" of the call.

Now, what is thread safe or unsafe here? I think this simply depends on what needs to be done. If you just need to avoid the list being corrupted and it doesn't matter if `first` is first or `second` is first in the list, for the application to run correctly, then just avoiding the corruption is enough to establish thread-safety. If it doesn't, it is not.

So, I think thread-safety can not be defined in the absence of the particular functionality we are trying to achieve.

The famous `String.hashCode()` doesn't use any particular "synchronization mechanism" provided in java, but it is still thread safe because one can safely use it in their own app. without worrying about synchronization etc.

Famous String.hashCode() trick:

```
int hash = 0;

int hashCode(){
    int hash = this.hash;
    if(hash==0){
        hash = this.hash = calcHash();
    }
    return hash;
 }
```